# How many requests does IcmpSendEcho2 send?

Tags: winapi, icmp

IcmpSendEcho2 documentation says:

> The ReplyBuffer contains the ICMP echo **responses**, if any.

For ICMP, if only one request is sent, wouldn't only zero or one responses be expected?

If that's the case, does that mean IcmpSendEcho2  can send multiple requests since it can receive multiple responses?  And if so, is there any way to find out how many requests were sent?

The goal of all this is to try and get a packet loss %, but knowing how many requests were sent needs to be known.

Answer (score 1):

`IcmpSendEcho2()` sends 1 request, but that can generate multiple responses.  The output is an array of responses, so you have to make sure the array is large enough to receive all of the responses.

Comment: That's what the documentation says.  But how does a single ping request generate multiple responses?  It makes me think IcmpSendEcho2 must send multiple requests.

Comment: I assure you, it only sends 1 request. But that request can be to a broadcast IP, for instance, in which case multiple machines may reply at one time.

Comment: Ahhhh, good point.  But if it is not sent to a broadcast address, then at most one response would be returned.  Is that correct?